# dotnet-ef is not compatible with net50

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net5

I'm using .NET 5 with Rider and trying to install dotnet-ef for working with migrations.

I got next packages installed:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design

But when typing `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ef` in the terminal i get the error, which says:

> Package dotnet-ef 5.0.7 is not compatible with net50 (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0) / any. Package dotnet-ef 5.0.7 supports: netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1) / any

Even when I run CMD as an admin I get the same error

So I clearly see that the latest version of dotnet-ef is for .NET 3.1. Is that really true? Is there no version of dotnet-ef for .NET 5? What can I be doing wrong?

I tried different versions of dotnet-ef and got different kinds of this error (depending on the choosen version).

Write in the comments if you need any other info.

Answer (score -2):

I got the same error when I try to use nuget to get the dotnet-ef :
But I tried in package manager console:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

and it works (difference is the --global).
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet

Comment: [`-g` and `--global` are synonyms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-install). This is exactly the same as the command in the question.